# jQuery img opacity/layer hover?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, opacity, fade

I have an img in a link that when you hover over it brings up a coloured/opacity layer over the top. It works fine apart from i need the name of the image to fade up as well.

So the image starts off on its own, but when you hover over an opacity colour appears as well as the name of the image.

Got everything apart from the name bit sorted, stuck on that.

Here is what i have so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasmE/)...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('ul.case-thumbs li').hover(function(){
      $('img', this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.6});
     }, function() {
      $('img', this).stop().animate({opacity: 1});
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jasmE/7/)**</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $('ul.case-thumbs li').on("mouseenter mouseleave",function ( e ) {
        var mEnt = e.type=="mouseenter";
        $('img', this).stop().fadeTo(300, mEnt?0.6:1);
        $('.thumbName', this).stop().fadeTo(300, mEnt?1:0);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="case-thumbs clearfix">
    <li>
        <div class="hover">
           <a href="#">
               <span class="thumbName">ImageName</span>
               <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-1123-900-1.jpg" alt="test" />
           </a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
span.thumbName{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    display:none;
}
ul.case-thumbs li {
    height: 165px;
    width: 220px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
}
ul.case-thumbs li img {
    vertical-align:middle;
    height: 165px;
    width: 220px
}
ul.case-thumbs li .hover {
    background-color: #560963;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if i am getting you or not but assuming this is what you want...
you are just changing the opacity of `<img>` here...and since image name is outside the img element... changing the opacity of  whole `<a>` element should work.. since the img and the image name is inside an anchor tag `<a>`

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('ul.case-thumbs li').hover(function () {
    $('a', this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.6
    });
}, function () {
    $('a', this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
});
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/jasmE/1/)

Comment: I dont want to be able to see the image/layer name until you hover over it. So would i need to put that in a span and 0 opacity?

Answer (score 0):

See this:  http://jsfiddle.net/hD7JK/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('ul.case-thumbs li').hover(function () {
    $('img', this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.6
    });
    $('span', this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
}, function () {
    $('img', this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
    $('span', this).stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
});
});
```

Html:

```
<ul class="case-thumbs clearfix">
  <li>
    <div class="hover"> <a href="#"> 
        <span>Image Name</span>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-1123-900-1.jpg" alt="test" /></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```